# Cannot update files on external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I recently upgraded my PC to Windows 7.  I blew away my previous install of XP to install a fresh Windows 7 system.  The problem I am having is with my external backup drive...

After the upgrade, I cannot make any changes to the files on the external hard drive.  The funny thing is, I can create new folders, and write / delete files in those new folders without a hiccup.  Its the files that were already on the disk before I performed the fresh install that are getting mad.

I ran through the diskpart commands - clearing the read-only values (the disk & volume attributes were not set to read-only to begin with).  At this point, I'm out of ideas and cannot find a solution... hoping to get one here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have an ownership issue?

Try right-click Properties on a troublesome folder. Go to the Security tab and then click "Advanced". Go to the owner tab and see who's listed as owner. To change, click "Edit..." and try switching owner to yourself. (be sure to check the checkbox about replacing on subdirectories as well).